# Impossible to deploy VDI infrastructure on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, vdi

I just tried to deploy a VDI insfrastructure with Windows server 2012 R2 on Microsoft Azure (Azure can't do VDI natively) but I can't virtualize desktops because we can't virtualize things in a virtualized environment.

Do you know a workaround to do VDI with Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - one of the services called [Azure RemoteApp is listed on the VDI page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/solutions/desktop-virtualization.aspx).
I can not say that RemoteApp is the pure VDI, but in the light of your question it should be considered, i think.

Comment: I'm trying to configure Azure RemoteApp but I think it's only for application virtualization...

Comment: You can virtualize your own server and upload that to the ARA.